# Catch Alarm Manager event In Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, broadcast, android-timer

I wonder is there any ways to  catch event by BroadCast receiver in Android. Because  I want to do stuffs in particular time. For instance: I want to update my room database in specific time. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you need. My data handling is all in the viewmodel.
So I just created an instance of Viewmodel and called it in onReceive() of the broadcast.

```
  // update toDO
        ToDoViewModel.instance?.apply {
             //logic here
        }
```

This is my code in ViewModel

```
 companion object {
    var instance: ToDoViewModel? = null
}
init {
    instance = this
}
```

Then onCleared I set instance to null to avoid memory leak.

```
 override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    instance = null
}
```

I hope this helps you.